# How can I cut paste a mobile number from column A to Column B only where the Column B is empty in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Here is the picture of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBHLw.jpg)

Looking for an easy way to do it because there are more than 500 entries like this where mobile number is in the address column.